# My stylesheet isn't working/being linked properly

Tags: html, css

My stylesheet isn't being linked on my webpage. I've got the code below in the `<head>` section of my HTML page. To better clarify, stylesheet.css is located in the same directory/path as my index.html.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
```

I expected it to correctly link my stylesheet but nothing is happening.

**EDIT:** Fixed it by removing the "."s before my function calls in my stylesheet. Thank you all for your help!

[Link to my project](https://pao.today/mrt/)

Comment: Make sure the name of the file is same as you added, If it's in the same directory

Comment: @user2682025 it is the same name.

Comment: @paoye I made little project and it works for me:https://codepen.io/leenmalka/project/editor/ZwWOqJ#0  maybe try to clean cache and hard reload

Comment: Add stylesheet.css content please

Comment: Sorry, but did you save in your css and html files and refreshed the browser ? Just in case.. :) Try to refresh it with Ctrl + Shift + R

Comment: If there is no path issues, and the CSS is valid then the old copy might be cached? 

Have you tried refreshing the page.

Comment: Force refreshing still reveals the same (old) style.

Comment: @PatrikAlexits, yes I saved the HTML and CSS files. The HTML changes fine every time I edit it, but not the stylesheet, so I figured it must be the HTML not calling the stylesheet properly?

Comment: Is it a local project (on your computer)? or online on a server or cloud?

Comment: try to compare between yours  to main:https://codepen.io/leenmalka/project/editor/ZwWOqJ#0

Comment: @user2682025 it's online. You can see it at https://pao.today/mrt

Comment: From the look of your html, you don't have any element with the class 'button'

Comment: It looks like it's working well from my side when I checked it, It must be your browser, check it with another browser like firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You issue is about [selector in css](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and not about file load**

As I see in F12 your file load:

[image]

But you don't have any `class="button"` as you have in css

**So add `class` to `button`** as `class="button"`

[image]

[**See working example**](https://codepen.io/leenmalka/project/editor/ZwWOqJ#0)

**Edit!**
Thanks to @Thomas Scheffer comment:

Remove also the `.` before `body` in css (you use `.body`)

Comment: Why add the class in html and not just remove the dots, both on body and button, in the css?

Comment: If the OP will have another button in html the style apply to the other button when you set `id/class` it is more spesific :https://css-tricks.com/why-use-classes-or-ids-on-the-html-element/

Comment: It that case i would use a less generic class name instead of `.button`

Comment: name of  `class` is opinion base :)

Comment: However you still missed the `.body` in your working example.

Answer (score 0):

Open your html file in e.g. Chrome and press F12.
If you link your css with bad path you will see on console error, something like this:
GET file:///......./stylesheet.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: No bad path error. I believe it might be my stylesheet itself actually.

Answer (score 0):

Often it could be a browser problem.

Try refreshing the page deleting cache files, in Chrome you can do that by pressing CTRL + F5.

If you're running a Linux based system, make sure that all the interested files have sufficient permissions to do so.